# Sending push notifications regarding a user's booking

Tags: ios, rest, go, expo

I have a REST API for a mobile app that handles bookings. It is written in Go using the go-fiber framework.

#### Data structure

```golang
type Booking struct {
  Active    bool      `bson:"active"`
  Created   time.Time `bson:"created"`
  StartDate time.Time `bson:"start_date"`
  EndDate   time.Time `bson:"end_date"`
}
```

#### Routes

`POST /bookings` to create a new booking

`POST /bookings/:id/start` to start a booking  ->  sets booking.Active = true

`POST /bookings/:id/end` to end a booking  ->  sets booking.Active = false

#### Goal

I don't expect every user to start their booking exactly when it was supposed to start, ad I don't expect them to end it when it was supposed to end. That's why it is necessary that I send the user mobile push notifications for:

"Your booking starts in 10 minutes."

"Your booking has started, please sign in."

"Your booking has ended, please sign out to avoid late fees."

#### Concern

I can use timers on the server-side to achieve this. It's as simple as a `time.AfterFunc()`, right?

But then those timers are gone once the server has to reboot. And that's a problem because  it is very important for the server to send those push notifications at their intended times.

I am currently using [Expo's Push Notifications API](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/) to send notifications. What is the best way to handle this? (If there are other solutions besides Expo that would better suit my situation, please share them). Looking for a scalable solution that won't break during API or even server restarts.

Comment: I'm not good at it. However, in my daily use, the reminder function of many apps is completed through the system's calendar event reminder, which simplifies a lot of operations.

Comment: I personally solved a similar issue by using a messaging queue (ex. Azure ServiceBus). I then implemented a nightly function which would scan the database for events that needed to be notified upcoming in the next 48h. The function then added Scheduled messages to the messaging queue which, once the enqueue scheduled time was reached, would be delivered to another function which then sent the notification to clients.

Comment: @Trock Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @akseli I had also read about using a messaging queue. But it seemed like an over engineered way to go about this. Surely, there is something more simple. Or maybe a push notification service that handles this for me instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just making a suggestion. This isn't a push feature anymore, it's a reminder feature. The app calls the system interface, adds the reminder event to the user's calendar, and the system will automatically remind the user of what schedule/action to do. Push card click can be done to open the app and jump to the specified page. Calendar reminders don't do that, they're just reminders.

Comment: How accurate do you need this to be? Within a minute? Within a second? You can simply poll every so often and send all the necessary messages.

Comment: @BurakSerdar All bookings are rounded by hour, so you're right, I guess I could do that and poll every hour. But since I'm using an external service to relay these notifications, wouldn't that result in a ton of ratelimits if there ends up being a lot of bookings? Expo has a limit of 600 notifications per second.

Comment: Second thought, great idea. I will implement hourly polling to publish these notifications. Thanks @BurakSerdar.

Comment: There is no way to avoid rate limiting if there is one. You are at the mercy of the traffic.

Comment: You should put a rate limiter on your end, sort the notifications, and hope for the best, If you have 10K notifications for a given moment, you'll send 600 per second, and most of them will be late.

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't be too much of an issue as long as they're sent within a minute or two. But what happens when the server goes down? If I poll every hour (as soon as it's 1:00, 2:00, etc), I'm querying the database for bookings that start in that hour. If the server somehow goes down for, say an hour, those previous notifications are never sent?

Answer (score 0):

This question is really more about infrastructure.

The most important factor in this is how often you want to push notifications and how many users would potentially expect to receive a notification. I'm assuming this is a small project so we can ignore the user-load component and just focus on the push frequency.

> Users don't like to be badgered with notifications.
>
> > -one of my bosses (i forgot when.. and who)

Assuming a period of longer than 1 minute, consider using cron-jobs, or some other system timer runner (i.e systemd services). If you're using Kubernetes then this is easy because cron-jobs are built in. In this case consider writing your program to run once to send all the notifications then quit. Then the system can wait and run the program again later.

If you want to push more frequently than a minute then an "in-code" solution is the way. I recommend a seperate go routine to unblock a channel at a predetermined interval, for example:

```golang
func LoopWait(dur time.Duration, handler func()) {
  block := make(chan struct{})
  go func() {
    for {
      time.Sleep(dur)
      select {
      case block <- struct{}{}:
      default:
      }
    }
  }()

  go func() {
    for {
      <-block
      handler()
    }
  }
}
```

This function will run handler at a frequency as reliable as go can get it. If the execution time of `handler()` is longer than `dur` then the next execution gets skipped.

Hope this helped.